# How to uncheck checked items in Navigation View?

Tags: android, navigationview, android-navigationview

I know it's possible to highlight a navigation view item by calling `setCheckedItem()` or return true value in `onNavigationItemSelected` to display the item as the selected item, but How can I uncheck the checked items of a navigation view?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This will uncheck the items:

```
    int size = mNavigationView.getMenu().size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setCheckable(false);
    }
```

Comment: i don't know after using your code it's giving me a blank space!

Comment: in my case, after using your technique, i got checked the last item and i can't resolve it. please help me...

Comment: @takmilul make sure you use `setChecked(false);` not `true`

Comment: with the code proposed the last item get selected. I solved the problem by replacing `setChecked(false)` with `setCheckable(false)`

Comment: `setCheckable(false)` combined with `setChecked(false)` for each item worked in my case.

Comment: Even though it **does** uncheck all items, it prevents the items from being checked in the future.

Comment: use setChecked(false)

Answer (score 41):

I saw @arsent solution and gave it a try, and it will indeed do what you want, which is to unselect all the items... but, I was having an issue in the following scenario:

1. Select menu item 1 (using `NavigationView#setCheckedItem`)
2. Unselect all the items as per @arsent's solution
3. Select menu item 1 again (using `NavigationView#setCheckedItem`)

In this scenario, item 1 will not be marked as checked. That's because internally the navigation view keeps track of the previously selected item set in step 1, which doesn't change in step 2, and it just skips step 3 because the previously selected item is the same as the one we're selecting now.

My suggestion (and an alternative solution) to avoid this is just having a dummy invisible item and use `NavigationView#setCheckedItem` to select that item whenever you want to unselect all, like so

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_none"
    android:title=""
    android:visible="false"/>
```

To unselect all just do

```
mNavigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.menu_none);
```

Comment: I found I also had to make that menu item `checkable="true"` for it to work, but once I did that, it's perfect!

Comment: this is even faster. smart solution!

Comment: Such a shame that similar feature isn't built in the SDK and we must hack on it

Comment: Such a smart hack!

Answer (score 21):

To uncheck all `MenuItems` including `SubMenu` items you have to use recursion -

```
    private void unCheckAllMenuItems(@NonNull final Menu menu) {
        int size = menu.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            final MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            if(item.hasSubMenu()) {
                // Un check sub menu items
                unCheckAllMenuItems(item.getSubMenu());
            } else {
                item.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Call above method for unchecking all items, like below -

```
unCheckAllMenuItems(navigationView.getMenu());
```

Answer (score 8):

just make your items non checkable like so

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/profile_item"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:title="@string/profile"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoting @Codeversed, there is "*no need to loop menu items with added overhead!*". But, there is no need to create multiple groups (in this case he is creating the `@+id/grp1` and `@+id/grp2`) to uncheck a previous checked item.

You can simple add a single group for all elements with  the `android:checkableBehavior`, like this:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawable1"
        android:title="@string/string1" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawable2"
        android:title="@string/string2" />
</group>
```

Answer (score 2):

Joao's solutions didn't not work for me as totally expected. This would lead to a blank space from unchecked Item View on my Navigation.

Just make sure to set the view as gone:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/your_menu_item_id_to_hide"
    android:title=""
    android:visible="false"/>


bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.your_menu_item_id_to_hide).setChecked(true);
    bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.your_menu_item_id_to_hide).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Arsent solution is not necessary in this case.

Comment: I had this same problem and I fixed it, but I can't remember right now how. Double check xml parameters on your layout files

Comment: ah that's a bottom navigation view, which is kind of recent. I've never tried my solution with that component, but good to know you managed to tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is surround your groups like this:

```
 <group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/grp1">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_24dp"
            android:title="@string/profile" />
    </group>
    <group
        android:id="@+id/grp2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_24dp"
            android:title="@string/settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/topic_help"
            android:title="@string/help_feedback" />
    </group>
</group>
```

No need to loop menu items with added overhead!

Answer (score 1):

I guess someone like me use those methods just like this

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_today:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_calendar:
           navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.nav_today, 0);
           navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);//or
           navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_today);//or
           drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
           break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Trying to check `R.id.nav_today` after you clicked on `R.id.nav_calendar`, (btw: `checkableBehavior="single"`), unfortunately it will not work.

That is because after your code `navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_today)` be called then the `R.id.nav_today` will be checked immediately, but after this, your click on  `R.id.nav_calendar` will check itself.

That is why whatever methods you use seem never work at all. It is work, but be override immediately.

Answer (score 1):

To uncheck it inside `NavigationItemSelectedListener` I had to use post (to UI thread):

```
App.getHandler().post(() -> menuItem.setChecked(false));
```

Full example:

```
 NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                menuItem -> {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);

                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        ...
                    }

                    App.getHandler().post(() -> menuItem.setChecked(false));

                    return true;
                });
```

p.s. in my case `App.getHandler()` returns `Handler` instance for UI Thread Lopper

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a combination of all the solutions mentioned here. In my case, I want to open an URL Intent when the Item is clicked (open a Browser). The clicked item should get unchecked after the click and reset to the item before. Important is to understand, that you cannot uncheck an item during the click listener event, since the checked state will be handled afterwards. So this is my solution in Kotlin:

```
        val item = navigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item)
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener {

            val oldItem = navigationView.checkedItem
            rootView.postDelayed({ // you can use here any View to post a Runnable with a delay
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(oldItem?.itemId ?: R.id.default_item)
            }, 500)
            browseURL("https://www.example.com")
            true
        }
```

I use a [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui) in combination with the [Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation).

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate you save my time.

Answer (score 0):

i combine @arsent  and @Rahul answers and write this code:

```
 private void NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            var size = navigationView.Menu.Size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
               var item= navigationView.Menu.GetItem(i).SetChecked(false);
                if (item.HasSubMenu)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < item.SubMenu.Size(); j++)
                    {
                        item.SubMenu.GetItem(j).SetChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            }
                e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);

            drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();

        }
```

above code is for xamarin c# and work,but u can easily convert to java

Answer (score 0):

@arsent's answer is correct but setCheckable(false) uncheck all items, it prevents the items from being checked in the future.

Just use setChecked(false)

```
  int size = mNavigationView.getMenu().size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
    }
```