# Bottom navigation bar remain checked after I go to that fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    loadFragment(new WalletFragment());

}

        private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
    if(fragment != null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_nav, fragment).commit();

        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.navigation_wallet:
            fragment = new WalletFragment();
            item.setChecked(true);
            break;

        case R.id.navigation_setting:
            fragment = new SettingFragment();
            item.setChecked(true);
            break;
    }

    return loadFragment(fragment);
}
```

I have only 2 items in bottom navigation bar menus. When I go in to the activity, it is in correct situation that I wanted. But when I choose another item menu in bottom navigation bar, the first one remains in the checked state. And when I choose to first menu item, the second one also remains in checked state.

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
 item.setChecked(true)
```

Do following

```
 int size = navigation.getMenu().size();
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
 {
    navigation.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have never unchecked any Menu items inside your switch-case statements. So, usually, the items should remain checked if they are not unchecked manually. Refer to the answer of this StackOverflow Question about [How to uncheck checked items in Navigation View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051045/how-to-uncheck-checked-items-in-navigation-view/36051131#36051131), where it shows how to uncheck all the elements:

```
int size = mNavigationView.getMenu().size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    mNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
}
```

So, to implement this in your code use that code in each of the cases:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){

    Fragment fragment = null;
    int size = navigation.getMenu().size();


    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.navigation_wallet:
            fragment = new WalletFragment();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                navigation.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
            }

            item.setChecked(true);
            break;

        case R.id.navigation_setting:
            fragment = new SettingFragment();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                navigation.getMenu().getItem(i).setChecked(false);
            }

            item.setChecked(true);
            break;
    }

    return loadFragment(fragment);
}
```